# Using Grunt.js with Drupal

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm in need of an organization system for my JavaScript code Drupal. Currently, I've got it inside a folder in my theme's directory: "`sites/all/themes/mytheme/js`". I've looked at using Grunt.js, and wondering how I might implement it into my website. How would it help me?

Can it help organize large JavaScript files?

Could it help improve the speed of my website?

Comment: Sorry to have to close this but it's completely off topic here - setting up grunt isn't related to Drupal in any way, the answer is the same for every type of website - you have some files in some folders, and you run some tasks on them. This would be a decent question for SO, but if wager it's already been asked and answered over there before. If there's a Drupal specific discipline involved here, please update the question and flag for reopening. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I started using Grunt.js by reading their easy to follow [tutorial](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started). Then, I created a Gruntfile.js inside of my theme’s js directory “`sites/all/themes/mytheme/js/Gruntfile.js`”:

```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
       pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
       concat: {
          main: {
             src: [
                'src/*.js',
             ],
             dest: 'production.js'
          }
       },
       uglify: {
          build: {
             files: {
                'production.min.js': 'production.js',
             }
          }
       },
       jshint: {
          files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/*.js'],
          options: {
             globals: {
                jQuery: true,
                console: true,
                module: true,
                document: true
             }
          }
       },
       watch: {
          files: ['src/*.js'],
          tasks: ['concat', 'jshint', 'uglify']
       }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

    grunt.registerTask('test', ['concat', 'jshint']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'jshint', 'uglify']);
  };
```

My Gruntfile does 3 things for me (right now):

1. Combines smaller, more manageable files inside `src/` into one file.
2. Checks for errors in my compiled file.
3. Compresses my file when I’m ready for production.

All I have to do is run `grunt watch` from the terminal and whenever one of the files inside `src/` is changed my `production.js` file is updated and compressed. When I’m all done debugging I just change the following in my .info file:

```
scripts[] = js/production[.min].js
```

This results in faster page loads because only one (smaller) request is being performed as opposed to many uncompressed file requests.